# Why does e.dataTransfer.files return 0 when dragging files from Android device

Tags: android, html, forms, drag-and-drop

I have a HTML files drag and drop form running fine from my Windows environment and I can drag and drop from my Windows folders onto the form, but when I try to drag from my Android device to my Windows environment I get zero files given (the Android connected over a cable).

I don't think this is a permissions thing, because I can load the file through the file button directly (I just can't drag and drop the same file).

I've provided a simple mock-up to demonstrate, but the guts of the code is

```
function dragend(e) {
   console.log('dragend');
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();

   var dndzone = e.target;
   var x = e.dataTransfer.files.length;
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert('Dropping ' + x + ' files');
}
```

a working example can be found on https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/xvtqasfn/40/

When you drag files onto the blue zone you get an alert to indicate how many files it thinks you're dropping.

Why would this return 0 from my phone?

Interestingly, using Windows File Manager, I can view some image files from my phones SD-card folders* but I cannot see any files in folders on my phones main "internal storage" folders. Not sure if this is a permissions issue as I'm not sure how to pin that down.

Any thoughts
Thanks
Abe

*I still cannot drag and drop them onto the page